# Removing all the entries pointing to a deleted object from a map

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

So here is the code I am dealing with:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){}
    virtual ~A(){}
    void Log(){printf("Log A\n");}
};

int main(int argc, char**argv) 
{
    A* a = new A();

    a->Log(); // "Log A"

    map<int,A*> m;
    m[1] = a;
    m[2] = a;
    m[3] = a;

    m[1]->Log(); // "Log A"

    delete a;
    a = NULL;

    m[1]->Log(); // "Log A"

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Log A
>   Log A
>   Log A

My questions:

1. Is it only by chance that calling `m[1]->Log()` does not throw exception after `delete a`?
2. What's the best approach to erase all the entries in the map pointing to the deleted instance of `A`? I mean I want all `m.find(1)`, `m.find(2)` and `m.find(3)` to return `m.end()` after deleting `a`. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution that may suit your requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Anything that happens when you dereference a deleted object is undefined behaviour, so even getting an exception could be considered to be "by chance"
2. <strike>The best approach is to couple the deletion of the object that is pointed to with the lifetime of something you have a handle on. So in your case, you could decide that it is best if the object is deleted if the pointer is removed from the map. To achieve this, you could use a map of int to `std::unique_ptr<A>` instead of one of  raw pointers.</strike>

**Edit**: After looking at the requirements in more detail:

Now, since you want to remove elements whose mapped type points to a deleted object, and there is no way to determine whether the memory a pointer points to has been deleted, I see no simple way of removing these entries from the map other than doing it all in one function call. And since `std::map` et al do not like `std::remove_if`, one can use a loop:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void removeEntriesAndDelete(std::map<T1, T2*>& m, T2*& item) {
  for (auto i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ) {
    if ( item == i->second) {
      m.erase(i++);
    } else {
      ++i;
    }
  }
  delete item;
  item=0;
} 

int main() {

  A* a = new A;
  std::map<int,A*> m;
  m[1] = a;
  m[2] = a;
  m[3] = a;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << a << ", " << bool(m[1]) << ", " << bool(m[2]) << ", " << bool(m[3]) <<"\n";

  removeEntriesandDelete(m, a);
 std::cout << a << ", " << bool(m[1]) << ", " << bool(m[2]) << ", " << bool(m[3]) <<"\n";
}
```

Comment: In his example, he actually had several pointers to the same object in the map, so `std::unique_ptr` can't be used.  (There's also nothing in what he said that suggests that the map is owner in some way of the pointers.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks, I realised I wasn't actually answering the second part of the question at all. In fact, I cannot think of any type of smart pointer that would solve OP's problem. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure (I might be wrong here) but I don't think this is correct. Don't iterators get invalidated after an `erase`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Only iterators to the erased element would be invalidated.

Comment: Yup, that's true. It doesn't apply to maps apparently.

Comment: I like your idea except for that it will be time consuming to search through all the map entries if it's a large map. I think one good approach would be to hold a list of all the keys pointing to the instance of A in the instance itself so that we have those keys and do not need to search for them.

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes and no. Technically it's **undefined behavior**, but *usually* (don't rely on this) calling non-virtual methods that don't access members appears to work on most compilers because most compilers implement this call without dereferencing `this` (which is the invalid part). So, in the standard's opinion, it's by chance. For most compilers, it's intended (or at least a side-effect of how function calls are handled).
2. Use smart pointers instead. To remove the elements, you can iterate through the map and compare each value to yours. When you reach one, use `erase`. <del>Iterators are invalidated after erase.</del>

Comment: @JamesKanze I'd use a `shared_ptr`. Juanchopanza recommends a `unique_ptr`, but I'm not sure that can work.

Comment: @JamesKanze just saw your comment on his answer. My thoughts exactly.

Comment: I have edited the second question. Could you please elaborate on the second part of your answer?

Comment: @Meysamرهادربند I can't think of a clean solution (+ you can't use a secondary map as iterators get invalidated). I added what I thought of.

Comment: shared_ptr would mess things up too, since it would keep the managed object alive, whereas OP wants to delete it and have all pointers pointing to the deleted memory be removed from the map...

Comment: @juanchopanza but when all elements are removed from the map, it would go out of scope.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I don't think a `shared_ptr` would work either, at least not in the general case.  Maps to pointers are usually used for navigation, which means cycles.  And in all of the cases where I've used them, objects needed deterministic destruction, in response to an external event, which isn't possible with `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Your first comment was the good one.  The goal is to automatically remove the entries from the map when the object is deleted, not vice versa.

Comment: @JamesKanze 2. deals with object removal. When all are removed, the object is destroyed.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Which is unlikely to be what is wanted.

Comment: @JamesKanze he's asking for alternatives, I believe this is one.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore It's an alternative which does something completely different and unrelated, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, objects which enrolled somewhere must notify the object where
they are enrolled.  In simple cases like your example code, it's
relatively simple to go through the map, erasing each element which
points to your object, but I assume that your actual use case is less
trivial.  The usual solution (in fact, the only one which really works
in practice) involves the observer pattern; when an object saves a
pointer to your object, either directly or in a map or a list or 
whatever, it also enrols with your object, requesting notification when
your object is destructed.  Your object keeps a list of these observers,
and will notify them in its destructor.  Applied to a simple case like
yours, it looks like a lot of unnecessary code, but in the context of
actual applications where this pattern occurs, it's not that much.

Answer (score 1):

It works by luck as you mention.

Either use something like smart pointers as previously mentioned, or encapsulate the map and value handling in a class, where you could have a method that removes the object from the map **and** deletes the object.

Comment: The fact that his class has a virtual destructor suggests that he might have to deal with polymorphic objects in the map.  Otherwise, of course, having the map contain values is the way to go.